# Changing name of uploaded image

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am working on a project that lets user to log in and upload some images on the website , 
I am using php5.
I have a question here that what if 2 different users uploaded 2 images with the same name to the date base. 
I know that I have to rename them as soon as they get to data base and I think I can do that using the current time value, But I do know the actual code. 
If any one can help me with that I really appropriate that

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: post your code so far

Answer (score 1):

tmpfile() will give you a unique file handle in your temp dir
 - or -
tempnam() will give you a unique file name in your temp dir

Use either one to create a unique file for the upload to save into, then you can rename them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

is best for you to send the image name to a datebase
than rename the image with the last id of your date base like this

```
  //////connect////////////////
include_once ("connect_to_mysql.php");

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$albumid = $_POST['album_id'];


 $maxfilesize = 8000000;

if($_FILES['image']['size'] > $maxfilesize ) { 
        echo "<br /><br />Your image was too large. Must be 8Mb or less, please<br /><br />
        <a href=\"Profilepic.php\">click here</a> to try again";
        unlink($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']); 
        exit();


} if (!isset($file))
 echo "Please select an Image.";
 else
 {

    // Check file size, if too large exit and tell them why

$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

$album_id = $_POST['album_id'];

$id = mysql_insert_id();

if ($image_size==FALSE)
echo "That's Not an Image.";
else
 {

if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO image
 VALUES('','$userid','$image_name')"))

echo "Problem Uploading Image Try Again Please";
else{
$id = mysql_insert_id();
//////////take the last inserted id and use as image name/////////
$file = "uploads/$userid/".$id."";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need a concept to make a file without making any conflicts, I like to would suggest following options.

Option 1: Rename as you want
Take the current users ID to a variable.

```
$tempName = $userID . "_" . strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . "_" . mt_rand();
```

Option 2: Separate locations
If you want to keep the same file name user uploads. Then store files in separate directories for each user.

You can use something like this.

```
$dirPath = "path to the user's directory";
if(!file_exists($dirPath))
mkdir($dirPath,0777);
```

When you upload apache will generate the file in temorary location, so it won't get duplicate.

Comment: Apache? Errrm, tempname is generated by php using the os.